# Sharepoint list keeps blinking after updating through Power Automate

Tags: json, list, sharepoint, hyperlink, power-automate

I managed to make a flow from a power apps form to power automate, that is supposed to update a sharepoint list.
[image: Start of flow][image: Initializing variables][image: Other variables][image: Start of try, creating array of input][![Parsing JSON with the following schema

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "DefaultDesc1": {},
            "DefaultDesc2": {},
            "DefaultDesc3": {},
            "DefaultDesc4": {},
            "DefaultDesc5": {},
            "DefaultUrl1": {},
            "DefaultUrl2": {},
            "DefaultUrl3": {},
            "DefaultUrl4": {},
            "DefaultUrl5": {},
            "DescLR1": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "DescLR2": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "DescLR3": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "DescLR4": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "DescLR5": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ItemId": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "UrlLR1": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "UrlLR2": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "UrlLR3": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "UrlLR4": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "UrlLR5": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "DefaultDesc1",
            "DefaultDesc2",
            "DefaultDesc3",
            "DefaultDesc4",
            "DefaultDesc5",
            "DefaultUrl1",
            "DefaultUrl2",
            "DefaultUrl3",
            "DefaultUrl4",
            "DefaultUrl5",
            "DescLR1",
            "DescLR2",
            "DescLR3",
            "DescLR4",
            "DescLR5",
            "ItemId",
            "UrlLR1",
            "UrlLR2",
            "UrlLR3",
            "UrlLR4",
            "UrlLR5"
        ]
    }
}
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRZiS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRZiS.png)[image: If the variable is different from the one found inside the list by default, then update the value of the array][image: Repeating the process for other variables][image: Repeating the process for other variables][image: Repeating the process for other variables][![Sending HTTP Request to SharePoint with body

```
{
    "Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref": {
        "Url": "@{variables('UrlLR1')}",
        "Description": "@{variables('DescLR1')}"
    },
    "Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref0": {
        "Url": "@{variables('UrlLR2')}",
        "Description": "@{variables('DescLR2')}"
    },
    "Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref1": {
        "Url": "@{variables('UrlLR3')}",
        "Description": "@{variables('DescLR3')}"
    },
    "Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref2": {
        "Url": "@{variables('UrlLR4')}",
        "Description": "@{variables('DescLR4')}"
    },
    "Legisla_x00e7__x00e3_o_x0020_Ref3": {
        "Url": "@{variables('UrlLR5')}",
        "Description": "@{variables('DescLR5')}"
    }
}
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbHGv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbHGv.png)[image: Continuation of HTTP Request][image: Catch that fires off if Try fails][![Sends Email detailing error, with the body

```
<style>
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>
<p>@{body('Criar_Tabela_HTML')}</p>
<a href='@{concat('https://make.powerautomate.com/environments/', workflow()?['tags']['environmentName'],'/flows/',workflow()?['name'],'/runs/',workflow()?['run']['name'])}'>Check flow Run</a>
</p>
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0170.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0170.png)[image: Terminates the flow]

The change is made, however the list itself keeps blinking until I reload the page.
The content of the list itself is updated correctly.
The problem is that, in SharePoint, after I submit the form for list A, said list keeps blinking back and forth, as if it was trying to load the content.
The flow is responsible for changing the description of Hyperlinks.
I don't even know where should I fix this.